# CakePHP: From 2.0 To 2.4 , is it worth it?

Tags: cakephp, migration

Our website was built using CakePHP 2.0 and currently the most recent version is 2.4.x .

I understand a more recent version has definitely some/many improvements over the earlier ones. However, my question is about the balance between improvement value and migration headache!

Is it worth it, performance wise mostly, to migrate from 2.0 cakephp to 2.4 one? or is it better to wait for 3.0 if improvement is not so big?

I could read all the differences and improvements from migration guides (and I did on some) but what I am looking for is the practical improvement that browsers of our website could see (e.g. speed of loading, look, security, features ..etc)

Comment: Guideline: Always upgrade to the current stable release of the major version. So the answer is: Yes.

Comment: I agree but my case is when you get hired long after this gab had already happened!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's start off with the fact that you are running 4 versions behind.

Only you can decide whether the information in the migration guides are actually beneficial to your application. You claim to have read them but something tell me you're skimming. The majority of the improvements are for the practicality of the developer... Let me cover some significant things that I found, but my answer will be subjective...

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-1-migration-guide.html

The introduction of `$this->fetch('content');` is probably the most significant thing here as something has been deprecated that your 2.0 is currently using. Everything else looks like either an improvement or an add-on of functionality.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html

Error handling has changed significantly, which will be the bulk of the changes required, otherwise no significant changes for you.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html

bcrypt support was added, this is a significant Security improvement and should be implemented for your passwords once you upgrade.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-4-migration-guide.html

Some deprecated methods. Again, don't know if you use them...

When I launched my website, I ran through the SitePoint guide for speed and how to leverage Caching, they suggest a 2.3 minimum to implement their suggested techniques. Also, if you did go through each migration, you will notice that caching gets mentioned a lot. I would also hedge my bets on technical backend issues not being listed on the migration pages above, so I was "assume" that speed and efficiently of random bits and pieces gets improved marginally.

http://www.sitepoint.com/speeding-up-your-cakephp-websites/

Should you upgrade before 3.0 hits? Definitely, if you where my client I assure you that I would hypothetically charge you a handful of hours for intermediary changes to the above, but if you where on 2.0 to 3.0 I would sting you for heaps more. I'd presume that there will be a concise 2.x to 3.0 guide that would streamline the process for the developer so it wouldn't take him as much time.

Comment: very beautiful summery. It's very helpful to know the main changes will be faced on each version sub-migration. At least, we can now estimate migration time! Thanks A LOT.